# Sort Numbers in varchar value in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

My Goal is to load a monthly-daily tabular presentation of sales data with sum total and other average computation at the bottom,

I have one data result set with one column that is named as 'Day' which corresponds to the days of the month, with automatic datatype of int.

```
select datepart(day, a.date ) as 'Day'
```

On my second result set, is the loading of the sum at the bottom, it happens that the word 'Sum' is aligned to the column of Day, and I used Union All TO COMBINE the result set together, expected result set is something to this like

```
day  sales
1      10
2      20
3      30
4      10
5      20
6      30
.
.
.
31     10
Sum   130
```

What I did is to convert the day value, originally in int to varchar datatype. this is to successfully join columns and it did, the new conflict is the sorting of the number

```
select * from #SalesDetailed
UNION ALL
select * from #SalesSum
order by location, day
```

Comment: as the error message suggested, you can have integer and string value on the same column. SQL Server will try to convert one to the other. In this case string to int. Which it can't do that and will fail. For such requirement, typicall, it is done at your reporting or front-end app. Not in sql server

Comment: So there are no means to achieve my desired result?

Comment: not exactly. Some awkward work around. You will have to convert the day to string. As you already found out returning sting to your app might mess up your app

Comment: @rickyProgrammer check if my answer works. It uses the "With Rollup" option for Group By

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your union query returns the correct results, just messes up the order, you can use `case` with `isnumeric` in the order by clause to manipulate your sort:

```
SELECT *
FROM
(
    SELECT *
    FROM #SalesDetailed
    UNION ALL
    SELECT *
    FROM #SalesSum
) u
ORDER BY location, 
         ISNUMERIC(day) DESC, 
         CASE WHEN ISNUMERIC(day) = 1 THEN cast(day as int) end
```

The `isnumeric` will return 1 when day is a number and 0 when it's not.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
select Day, Sum(Col) as Sales 
from #SalesDetailed
Group by Day With Rollup
```

**Edit (Working Sample)** :

```
select 
CASE WHEN Day IS NULL THEN 'SUM' ELSE STR(Day)  END  as Days, 
Sum(Sales)  from 
( 

Select 1 as Day , 10 as Sales UNION ALL
Select 2 as Day , 20 as Sales

) A 
Group by Day With Rollup
```

**EDIT 2:**

```
select CASE WHEN Day IS NULL THEN 'SUM' ELSE STR(Day)  END  as Days,
       Sum(Sales) as Sales 
from #SalesDetailed
Group by Day With Rollup
```

Comment: Thanks! I will try this

Comment: @rickyProgrammer It most certainly will work what was the query you tried? Perhaps I should have posted a query with actual tablenames and columns ... see the edit